# Reasonse to define an Service Endpoint Interface for an JAX-WS web service?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

What benefits does it bring if a Service Endpoint Implementation class explicitly references a Service Endpoint Interface, like in the following code snippet?

```
@WebService(endpointerInterface = "foo")
public class Bar {
    public String getFoo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It links your implementation to the definition of web service. It's popular, but it's better to use "implements Foo". Because in your case compiler can't check whether you implemented all methods in the web service.